# Intercept outgoing browser HTTP requests

Tags: jquery, http, interceptor

I have a web application.  Is it possible for my app to monitor all outgoing client browser HTTP requests that originate from my app?  If it is, is it possible to intercept them and cancel them at will?  Is there a JQuery HTTP interceptor, in particular?

Comment: This is an interesting question.. what is the use case?

Answer (score 2):

This is possible with JQuery using ajaxSetup.beforeSend

```
$.ajaxSetup({
  beforeSend: function(xhr) {
      //do your stuff here
  }
});
```