# How to intercept outgoing HTTP requests of browser?

Tags: javascript, html, http, browser, intercept

I have some untrusted code running on my website, inside iframes.

The iframes can make requests to other websites, but I want to be able to intercept requests that shouldn't be allowed.

Because there are so many different ways to make a request (submitting a form in html, contacting a server in javascript, loading an image in CSS, ...) I need a blanket solution that will let me intercept all requests.

This question is similar, but the answer does not actually work for any request that wasn't done with Ajax: [Intercept outgoing browser HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612108/intercept-outgoing-browser-http-requests)

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot intercept requests, but you can use `sandbox` iframe attribute to decide what's allowed and what not, such as:

```
<iframe sandbox=”allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-popups” src=”...”></iframe>
```

Here's a writeup on it: https://blog.dareboost.com/en/2015/07/securing-iframe-sandbox-attribute/

Comment: I am already using a sandbox. Unfortunately, I can't find a way to prevent the iframe from accessing external websites with something as simple as a linked css stylesheet. It is possible to leak small amounts of user data by putting that data in the url of the stylesheet.